# Simple web page will not run on xbox one edge browser

Tags: node.js, xbox-one

I am starting to learn html, css, and nodejs, and after writing a couple of very basic web pages I tried to run them on my computer, and view the page on my xbox-one with edge, but for each one (no matter how simple) it always says "Application is not supported, The webpage tried to start an application, such as an email program, that is not supported on xbox". I've tried with using the node html library as well as the express library, with and without html/css.

One code that would not work on the xbox:
server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    res.end("hello world!");
})

var PORT = 1021;

server.listen(PORT);
console.log("Server is running on 192.168.0.15:", PORT, '\n');
```

I can't find anything online, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There's a HUGE difference between displaying an HTML file and running a node.js server.  You just can't run node.js on an xbox, plain and simple.  Try running node somewhere else and then using your xbox to view the page.

Comment: @Graham Sorry I guess I was a bit misleading. I am running these servers on my desktop and trying to view them on my xbox

Comment: You may want to edit the question to make that more clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of trial and error I found out that it was a very simple problem, I was putting 192.168.0.15:12345 into the address bar but it wanted http://192.168.0.15:1021.